# Default user sign up with Devise not working in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed the Devise gem like normal in my rails project. I then ran `rails generate devise:install` followed by `rails generate devise User`.

I ran `rake db:migrate`

I restarted my rails server.

My route file has the following:

```
devise_for :users
```

My model looks like such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :lockable, :timeoutable
end
```

I haven't added any custom fields.

When I go to users/sign_up and fill out the form with an email address and password it tells me the form was blank:

> 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
>   Email can't be blank
>   Password can't be blank

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of devise, exactly?

Comment: @gregates I used gem 'devise' in my GemFile, so I assume 3

Comment: can you look in your Gemfile.lock to get the exact version?
also, have you customized controllers or views at all?

Comment: @gregates version 3.2.0. No customized controllers. I initially ran `rails generate devise:views` but removed that folder to trouble shoot.

Comment: To try to isolate the problem, can you examine the server log when you submit the form and see what the params for the POST request look like?

Comment: @gregates here is the error I'm getting: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation

Comment: Sounds silly, but did you restart rails server?

Comment: @RussellKompinski it's not silly, I thought that was my issue. I've restarted several times.

Comment: Aha. Are you sure you're on Rails 4? It seems like you're still using Rails 3 mass assignment protection instead of controller-based strong params, which is the default in Rails 4.

Comment: Mass Assignment is over with. You're supposed to be using Stron Parameters

Comment: If you are still intentionally using mass assignment protection, you can fix this by setting `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation` on your `User` model.

Comment: Interesting... I know I'm using Rails 4. To double check I looked in my GemFile. gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

Comment: btw, yea that's totally the issue @jmcharnes - Mass Assignment Shouldn't be in rails 4. Make sure you have the right devise version. Did you maybe put devise gem, and used your sytems without running a bundle install?

Comment: Any ideas to why it's using mass assignment protection? I'd like to be using strong params.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes then? It's possible to add mass assignment protection back in to Rails 4, but it's not there by default.

Comment: You may want to re-run the Devise installer.  This issue can happen if you initally setup devise with an old version of the gem.

Comment: run something like bundle update devise

Comment: It was user error! For some reason when I added `gem 'devise'` I also added `gem protected_attributes`. When I removed `protected_attributes` and restarted the server I was up and running again. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer and accept it, just so this question shows up as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason when I added `gem 'devise'` I also added `gem 'protected_attributes'`. When I removed `protected_attributes` and restarted the server I was up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add something like following lines in your application_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password ) }
  end
```

Comment: authentication keys and password are permitted by default on sign up